# installing a python package in a virtual environment

Tags: python, curl

I started a virtual environment and installed egcurl from https://github.com/akamai-open/edgegrid-curl like this:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install httpie-edgegrid
```

However, when I try to run it like this:

```
egcurl -X POST -uadmin:admin SOME_URL
```

I get:

```
-bash: ./egcurl: No such file or directory
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running it with `./` at the beginning of the program name?

Comment: Notice that the Readme is actually saying `httpie-edgegrid` is another package you might want to use instead. If you still want to use this one, just clone the repo or download it. It's a single python file. Edit: and put it in venv/bin.

Answer (score 2):

The installation instructions are quite poor, and don't make it clear that the `egcurl` script needs to be installed separately. To get it working properly, follow these steps:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install edgegrid-python
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akamai-open/edgegrid-curl/master/egcurl > venv/bin/egcurl
$ chmod +x venv/bin/egcurl
$ egcurl --help
```

Note that `httpie-edgegrid` is a different utility which doesn't use the `egcurl` script at all. If you want to know how to use it, take a look at this [README](http://github.com/akamai-open/httpie-edgegrid/blob/master/README.rst).

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

```
which egcurl
```

This will probably tell you it is trying to execute egcurl in the directory you are currently in and report something like "./egcurl." 
You can either cd into the folder that contains egcurl which, if you are using virtualenv, should be in workspace/lib/... Then run your script.

If you have trouble finding egcurl do the following:

```
find / -name "egcurl"
```

Then you can setup an alias to the absolute path or add it to the virtualenv activate script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command:

```
pip show httpie-edgegrid
```

This will show you useful information, like where the package is installed. Example:

```
(venv) bruno@bbc-host:~/venv$ pip show httpie-edgegrid
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: httpie-edgegrid
Version: 1.0.4
Summary: Edgegrid plugin for HTTPie.
Home-page: https://github.com/akamai-open/httpie-edgegrid
Author: Kirsten Hunter
Author-email: khunter@akamai.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/bruno/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: httpie, pyOpenSSL, edgegrid-python
Classifiers:
Entry-points:
  [httpie.plugins.auth.v1]
  httpie_oauth1 = httpie_edgegrid:EdgeGridPlugin
```

Make sure the package is installed in your venv and not in a global directory.

Although I think solarc is right, this package is probably not the one that allows you to use egcurl. You are installing this one: https://github.com/akamai-open/httpie-edgegrid